# asci hex to blob sql

Tags: sqlite, binary, hex

So I have a u-tf eight string represented in little endian

```
73 74 61 6b 20 66 6c 6f 77 20 73 75 63 6v 73 0a
```

how would I insert this into a sqlite3 table as a blob?  Reading from a file is not a option.  Has to start as a string.  Bash would be preferred but a example in any  modern scripting language is cool, batch, power-shell - not the sqlite command line.

To be clear, I am asking for a example not a explanation.

Comment: Are you using an application language with SQLite, such as Java or Node.js?  If so, then you may just convert the hex to binary and then write as a BLOB.  Nots sure where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

***notcode***bin=$(/bin/echo -n "x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a\x0a"|xxd -r -p) &&sqlite3 db.db 'insert into (bin) VALUES ($bin);'

seems to work for bash. You will run into trouble using the upper 127 unicode assci table.  Bash doesn't account and will break on most things.  python or perl handle explicit encoding pretty well but there is a one line answer.  In the form of a example not a question.  SO ODD.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a [blob literal](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#litvalue):

```
db.execute("INSERT INTO bin VALUES(x'7374616b20666c6f77207375636b730a')")
```